# Can euclidean space be written as $X \times X$ for some topological space $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Can $\mathbb{R}^n$ be written as $X \times X$ for some topological space $X$?  This is obviously true if $n$ is even.  Take $X = \mathbb{R}^{n/2}$.   However, I'm unsure about $n$ odd.

Comment: See: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60375/is-r3-the-square-of-some-topological-space

Comment: That MO thread *does* answer the general question.

Comment: @AymanHourieh True. I have edited my comment.

Comment: I believe that this isn't true. Why? Let $(x,y)\in X\times X$. Then, let $(X,Y,Z,...,X^{2n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$. We would expect that a point $(x,y)=(X,Y,Z,...,X^{2n+1})$. Note the discrepancy here. There are an odd number of elements on the RHS, however, there are two, i.e., even number of elements on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this isn't true. Why? Let $(x,y)\in X\times X$. Then, let $(X,Y,Z,...,X^{2n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$. We would expect that a point $(x,y)=(X,Y,Z,...,X^{2n+1})$. Note the discrepancy here. There are an odd number of elements on the RHS, however, there are two, i.e., even number of elements on the LHS.

The above statement is right. Let me prove it formally. Let $\mathcal{H}:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ be a homeomorphism. Then, there exists a homeomorphism $X\times X\times X\times X\to\mathbb{R}^{4n+2}$. There exists a map $h:X\times X\times X\times X\to X\times X\times X\times X$ such that $h\circ h$ is orientation preserving. You can show, that when $h\circ h$ is acted upon $\mathbb{R}^{4n+2}$, the map is non-orientation preserving. Hence, $X\times X\times X\times X$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{4n+2}$, and hence, $X\times X$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ either. Q.E.D.

Comment: I don't see how this proof works. Can you explain the "You can show" part?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Take $h:(a,b,c,d)\to(d,a,b,c)$.